# Flatness and dualizing sheaf of a family of curves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

I´m trying to see if the following holds: Given a family of curves $\pi:X\rightarrow S$ where $\pi$ is proper and flat and the schemes $X$ and $S$ are arbitrary is it true that the relative dualizing sheaf exists? Moreover, I would like to know if considering a vector bundle $E$ on $X$ and flat over $S$, the tensor product of $E$ with the relative dualizing sheaf is flat. Thank you for your time.

Comment: What about the case where X is a proper and not Cohen Macauley with S being spec(k) ?

Comment: I don’t know under what conditions over X the above statement it’s true, that’s the reason why I am asking. I haven’t worked with Cohen-Macaulay schemes yet :S

Comment: @J.Ove: you should specify what you mean by "dualizing sheaf". A "dualizing complex" exists under rather general circumstances. Sometimes the "main" cohomology sheaf of that is called (somewhat incorrectly) the "dualizing sheaf". If you meant a sheaf with actual dualizing power, then it is essentially what Adam is saying. You need the map to be a CM morphism. You can look these things up for example in Brian Conrad's book or on the stacks project.